# WPF create a custom control

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I want to build a custom control in WPF but I don't know what to use. I want to achieve the following:

Control sketch
[image]

So there are two different textblocks (header and hint) and also a path for the icon.

I need this control multiple times in one view but the itemssource is not a list (so I can't take an itemscontrol and a datatemplate).

How would I do it the best way?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Visual Studio there is a template for WPF Custom Controls Library (as well as a template for WPF custom control)
2. I suppose you're used to creating XAML so the markup will not be covered
3. To allow binding data items to your control from XAML you need to create dependency properties in your control code:

```
     public string Header {
        get => (string) GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);}
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = // note naming - <PropName>+Property
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Header), typeof(string), typeof(YourControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));
```

Repeat this code for each property you want to expose

This way you can bind properties in XAML using `<YourControl Header="text" />` or `<YourControl Header={Binding SomeProp} />`

4. Once you created all the needed props, you can easily bind to them in control's XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Header} />
```

Comment: And how does the binding inside of the controls xaml work?

Comment: @RobertM I've updated the answer. In general - the same way you use binding in other places, once you create DependencyProperties, Intellisense will add them to hints while you edit XAML